# Initial setup after upgrade, how to do backup?

Tags: upgrade

Today I got an alert that I can upgrade my Ubuntu to 19.10. So I started the upgrade. After the Upgrade I restarted my PC. All went fine, but one program however was uninstalled. I installed it and restarted my computer. Now after decrypting my hard disk I can not log in to my user. It does an initial setup. Strg Alt T doesn't open the terminal. I can't do anything.

When I press arrow key up before decrypting my hard disk I see that it says "volume group Ubuntu-vg not found. Can not process volume group Ubuntu-vg."

How do I fix this? If possible I would like to do a backup of my data and then just do a fresh install. Is that possible?

Comment: The title of this question does not match the description. That makes it harder for folks with the knowledge to find your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not login to my user"? No login screen? Access denied? Login loop? Display server crash? Something else? It's not clear what problem you are having.